# How NFS lock works in pNFS

Tags: linux, nfs, nfs4

As I know, pNFS is an extended protocol over NFSv4.1. Does anyone have any information about how the NFS lock works on Parallel NFS (pNFS)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pNFS support file share and byte-range locks as NFSv4. Please refer to the address https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5661#section-12.5.1